# ASP.NET Nested Data Bound Controls

Tags: asp.net, formview

Say I have a Form View with a Repeater inside of it, and then a Data List nested inside of the Repeater. If I had an Update Command in the DataSource for the Form View would I be able to associate bound values within the Data List to parameters in the Form Views' DS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always go up using .NamingContainer up to the container that has the data you want, and access through .DataItem.

Something around the lines:

((ContainerType)Container.NamingContainer.NamingContainer).DataItem ...